# R: writing loop that skips item in case file is not found, but breaks in case of other errors

Tags: r, loops, error-handling, try-catch, skip

I would like to write a loop that skips to the next item in case a csv file is not found, but that stops in case of any other error after reading the csv file.

The code below goes through all the items in the loop (`1:5`), skip items for which there exists no file (`item==2, 3, 5`) but does not break in case of errors in the following commands after the file is assigned to `df0`. I would like the code to break after reading `A_4` given that this object does not contain the column `id1`.

```
A_1 <- data.table(id1 = c(1:5, 7))
A_4 <- data.table(id4 = 1:100)
fwrite(A_1,"output_1.csv")
fwrite(A_4,"output_4.csv")

for(item in c(1:5)) {
  tryCatch({
    print(item)
  df0 <- fread(paste0("output_",item,".csv"))
  df0[,.(id1)]
  }, error=function(e){cat("file not found \n")})
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? It works for me? I.e. the `file not found` error is shown for 2,3,4,5

Comment: The code above skips all sorts of errors. The loop does not break in case the file is not found (as you point out) as well as in case of any other errors. I would like the code to break in line `df0[,.(id1)]` when `df0` is assigned to be `A_4` to `df0`. The code should break because `A_4` has no column called `id1`.

Comment: I think it does break.  Try `error=function(e) {print(e)}` instead, and you will see that it breaks for 2,3,5 because the file is not found, and it breaks for 4 because id1 is not found.

Comment: [1] 1
[1] 2
<simpleError: File 'output_2.csv' does not exist or is non-readable. getwd()=='<path>'>
[1] 3
<simpleError: File 'output_3.csv' does not exist or is non-readable. getwd()=='<path>'>
[1] 4
<simpleError in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()): object 'id1' not found>
[1] 5
<simpleError: File 'output_5.csv' does not exist or is non-readable. getwd()=='<path>'>

Comment: Thank you @langtang. What I mean is that I would like the code not to loop over to the next item in case of errors other than not finding the file. i.e., I would like it to loop over to item 3 when file 2 is not found, but I would like it to stop and not loop to item 5 once there is an error in `df0[,.(id1)]` within item 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple `if`/`else` block

```
for(item in c(1:5)) {
  fname = paste0("output_",item,".csv")
  if(file.exists(fname)) {
    df0 <- fread(fname)
    df0[,.(id1)]
  }
  else print("file not found")
}
```

This will print your `file not found` messag if the file is not found, and then move to the next value of `item`. If the file is found, it will read it, and then evaluate `df0[,.(id1)]`. If `id1` is not a column in `df0`, it will stop, which I think is what you want.

Comment: I would like `df0[, .(id1)]` to run only for the items for which there is a corresponding file. My data is massive and my real code is quite long - this would make a big difference. Isn't there a simple way in which I can tell R to continue to the next item in the loop when there is an error in the `fread` line?

Comment: You could put a `select` in `fread` that selects for (all) proper number/names of column that seems would combine these tests, or so it seems.